# Require JS with Ember not concatenating

Tags: optimization, ember.js, requirejs

I'm trying to get the RequireJS Optimizer process to work with my ember application. So far it is minifying the JS and CSS but not concatenating things properly into the one file. I think it has something to do with my build.js file.

Here's my hierarchy:

```
images
scripts
    app
        controllers
        models
        routes
        templates
        views
        mixin.js
        main.js
        router.js
    libs
    plugins
    config.js for require
    entry.js
source
    coffee-script version of above
styles
index.php
build.js
r.js
```

And my build.js file looks like this:

```
({

    appDir: "./",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    dir: "../pubdash-built",
    fileExclusionRegExp: /^(templates|source)$/,
    mainConfigFile: "scripts/entry.js",
    name: "entry",
    removeCombined: false,
    optimizeCss: "standard.keepLines",
    inlineText: true
})
```

I know it's a bit extreme but entry.js starts everything as my require data-main. It requires() config.js which shims and sets paths and then requires() Ember and App (which is main.js) to actually initialize the whole ember application.

build.js finds everything, excludes my coffee and templates but isn't concatenating anything or inlining my template html files.

Any ideas on where I'm slipping up?

Comment: So I worked out my script but it seems to be sub-optimal. I just added the paths and shim objects from my config.js, and put in the     findNestedDependencies: true flag (which might not be necessary). It works but I hoped to just specify the mainConfigFile and not have to have these properties!

Answer (score 0):

Please define your module. As per example given below all your files will be optimized to single module "entry"

```
({

appDir: "./",
baseUrl: "scripts",
dir: "../pubdash-built",
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(templates|source)$/,
mainConfigFile: "scripts/entry.js",
name: "entry",
removeCombined: false,
optimizeCss: "standard.keepLines",
inlineText: true,
modules: [
    {
        name: "entry"
    }   
]
})
```